# Determining a Polynomial for a Given Improper Integral

Tags: calculus

Hello I got this problem on my calculus exam last year and it still hunts me to this day. Here is the problem: $P(x)$ is a polynomial and
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{P(x)}{x^4-x}dx = 1$. Determine $P(x)$

A solution for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want $P$ to 'cancel out' the roots of $x^4 - x$ so that the integrand is finite there. Indeed, if we try $P(x) = x(x-1)$, then \begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{P(x)}{x^4 - x} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x(x-1)}{x(x^3-1)} \, \mathrm dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + x + 1} \, \mathrm dx \\
&= \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt 3}
\end{align*}
which can be shown by completing the square and a tangent substitution. So, $$P(x) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2 \pi} x(x-1)$$
works for the problem. (And is the unique solution as mentioned by @Svyatoslav in the comments.)

Comment: This is also the only possible polynomial which ensures the convergence of the integral at $\pm\infty$. Hence, the solution is unique.